# Error in your SQL syntax. Update table issue

Tags: php, sql

I really hate that error message, since it is the most useless error message in the history of man.

Anyhow I think I have stared at this VERY simple `sql` for an hour and still come up blank as to where it believes the problem is. Hope someone can help me or maybe some rubber ducking will do the trick.

The php code:

```
$sql    =   "UPDATE events SET titel = '$this->estart',
                                        endTime = '$this->eend',
                                        desc = '$this->desc',
                                        dd = '$this->dDmed',
                                        dato = '$this->dato',
                                        ticketId = '$this->ticket' WHERE id = $this->id";
```

And the SQL error thrown:

```
right syntax to use near 'desc = '2222222222222222',
                                    dd = 'shop',
                                    dato = '2015-01-14' at line 3[ UPDATE events SET    titel = '08:30:00',
                                    endTime = '09:00:00',
                                    desc = '2222222222222222',
                                    dd = 'shop',
                                    dato = '2015-01-14',
                                    ticketId = '2222222222222' WHERE id = 4]' in  ....
```

the table layout:

```
 id         int(11)
 titel      varchar(200)
 navn       varchar(200)
 email      varchar(255)
 tlf        varchar(20) 
 domæne     varchar(150)
 kundNumb   int(14)
 abnId      varchar(15)
 startTime  time
 endTime    time
 desc       text 
 ticketId   varchar(20)
 dd         varchar(5)
 dato       date
```

Hope someone can assist, I am sick and tired of that `sql` statement.

Comment: What is the table structure?

Comment: what type is ticketId? here you pass it in as a string, but it might be an int? Also, check that the date is in the correct format for your server..

Comment: Ticket id is xx-111-44444444443 so a string not an int. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `desc` field. `DESC` is a keyword in the SQL syntax. So you will have to quote desc with back-ticks like this `` `desc` ``.

```sql
UPDATE events SET 
    `titel` = '$this->estart',
    `endTime` = '$this->eend',
    `desc` = '$this->desc',
    `dd` = '$this->dDmed',
    `dato` = '$this->dato',
    `ticketId` = '$this->ticket'
WHERE id = $this->id
```

Comment: You where right.. desc is ofcause also Descending and thus a reserved word, hence it should be in `desc` and once I did that.. it worked .. for anyone who might bump into a simular issue. in MySQL single quotes won't work I had to use ` <-- this sign to make it work.

Comment: It's best to avoid it at all as it's plain confusing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a comma:

```
$sql    =   "UPDATE events SET titel = '$this->estart',
                                        endTime = '$this->eend',
                                        desc = '$this->desc',
                                        dd = '$this->dDmed',
                                        dato = '$this->dato',
                                        ticketId = '$this->ticket' WHERE id = $this->id";
```

Comment: Not the problem, just a type error from my side.. thx tho :)

Still the problem persists.

Comment: the comma is not the only problem - still missing some syntax so query can work.

Comment: yup, pasted the new error into my original post and corrected my type error :)

problem is the same

Comment: I think that the Kiyan's answer is the right one. Desc is a reserved word so if you use it as one of your field you have to use ' or " in your queries or write events.desc

Answer (score 0):

Seems Error is in ticket_ID i think you are using ticket_id as number type or integer type and passing it as string `'$this->ticket'` remove '' and keep it as `$this->ticket`

Comment: id is passed as intiger I belive:

    $obj->id = intval(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']));

Comment: and the ticket id is a varchar since it's a string :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing

```
ticketId = '$this->ticket'
```

to

```
ticketId = $this->ticket
```

should work..

Answer (score -1):

you miss a comma, and some " and '. :

```
"UPDATE events SET titel = '".$this->estart."',
   endTime = '".$this->eend."',
   desc = '".$this->desc."',
   dd = '".$this->dDmed."',
   dato = '".$this->dato."',
   ticketId = '".$this->ticket."' WHERE id = ".$this->id.";
```

Comment: You did notice his query values printed correctly? When using `"` in PHP you can call variables within the string. When using `'` you cannot.